# Whats the best way to create a new Map?

Tags: javascript, dictionary

Need some help, this works but need a better of doing it. I just need to map some info into a new object (thats also nested) and push them into an array. Is there a cleaner way of achieving the same thing? I'm working in javascript

```js
const newArray = (info) => {
        let itemArray = [];
    
        info.forEach((item) => {
            var itemObj = {
                product: {
                    id: '007',
                    description: 'something'
                },
                quantity: 1,
                'price': {
                    amount: 1.99,
                    currency: 'GBP',
                },
                'tt_price': {
                    amount: 1.99,
                    currency: 'GBP',
                },
            };
    
            itemObj.product.id = item.sku;
            itemObj['price'].amount = item.price;
            itemObj['tt_price'].amount = item.price;
            itemObj['price'].currency = item.currency
            itemObj['tt_price'].currency = item.currency
            itemObj.product.description = item.name
    
            itemArray.push(itemObj);
        });
        return itemArray
    }
```

Comment: "*but need a better of doing it*" - in what way do you think the code is bad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array#map` to create a new Array using new values returned in the function:

```js
const newArray = info => info.map(item => ({
  product: {
    id: item.sku,
    description: item.name,
  },
  quantity: 1,
  price: {
    amount: item.price,
    currency: item.currency,
  },
  tt_price: {
    amount: item.price,
    currency: item.currency,
  },
}));
```

> Notice that `newArray` is a function and not an array, so don’t forget to call it

Comment: Thanks! thats a lot cleaner!!